# tracking IP addresses

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic

I want to track IP addresses visited my website. I want to know what time and what page they visit. I store ip address in VISITORIP, date entered in DATEENTERED and page URL in HTTPADDRESS columns.

I want to group them by dates. My outcome should be like:

```
TIME                    PAGE
 7/12/2009
3:16:27 PM  ?Section=products&SubSection=products&CATEGORYID=1
2:46:50 PM  ?Section=products&SubSection=products&CATEGORYID=8
2:20:45 PM  ?Section=products&SubSection=products&CATEGORYID=11
 7/11/2009
9:34:28 AM  ?Section=products&SubSection=products&CATEGORYID=7
9:33:31 AM  ?Section=products&SubSection=products&CATEGORYID=2
 7/10/2009
9:53:16 PM  ?Section=products&SubSection=products&CATEGORYID=9
9:34:14 PM  ?Section=products&SubSection=products&CATEGORYID=4
9:27:11 PM  ?Section=products&SubSection=products&CATEGORYID=3
9:15:47 PM  ?Section=products&SubSection=products&CATEGORYID=15
```

Problem is, I could not group them by dates. I get the outcome as:

```
07/12/2009
7/12/2009 3:16:27 PM    /html/default.aspProcess=HomeNewSeason&IMAGECONTENT=bg_home_newtaste.gif
7/12/2009 3:16:27 PM    /html/default.aspProcess=HomeBestSeller&IMAGECONTENT=bg_home_customerschoice.gif
07/12/2009
7/12/2009 3:16:27 PM    /html/default.aspProcess=HomeNewSeason&IMAGECONTENT=bg_home_newtaste.gif
7/12/2009 3:16:27 PM    /html/default.aspProcess=HomeBestSeller&IMAGECONTENT=bg_home_customerschoice.gif
07/09/2009
7/9/2009 5:37:02 PM     /html/default.aspSection=checkout
07/09/2009
7/9/2009 5:37:02 PM     /html/default.aspSection=checkout
07/09/2009
7/9/2009 5:37:02 PM     /html/default.aspSection=checkout
```

My codes:

```
<%
        Case "TrackIP"

        IPADDRESS = Request.QueryString("IPADDRESS") 

    SQL = "SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEENTERED, 101) AS DATEENTERED"
    SQL = SQL & " FROM STATS"
    SQL = SQL & " WHERE VISITORIP = '"& IPADDRESS &"'"
    SQL = SQL & " GROUP BY DATEENTERED" 
    SQL = SQL & " ORDER BY DATEENTERED DESC"
    Set objDateEntered = objConn.Execute(SQL)   
%>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Time</th>
                <th>Page</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
<% Do While Not objDateEntered.EOF %>
            <tr class="row-title">
                <td colspan="2"><%=objDateEntered("DATEENTERED")%></td>
            </tr>
<%
    SQL = "WITH LASTVISIT AS ("
    SQL = SQL & " SELECT VISITORIP, MAX(DATEENTERED) AS DATEENTERED"
    SQL = SQL & " FROM STATS"
    SQL = SQL & " WHERE VISITORIP = '"& IPADDRESS &"' AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEENTERED, 101) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), '"& objDateEntered("DATEENTERED") &"', 101)"
    SQL = SQL & " GROUP BY VISITORIP"
    SQL = SQL & " )"
    SQL = SQL & " SELECT STATS.VISITORIP, STATS.HTTPADDRESS, STATS.DATEENTERED"
    SQL = SQL & " FROM STATS"
    SQL = SQL & " INNER JOIN LASTVISIT"
    SQL = SQL & " ON LASTVISIT.VISITORIP = STATS.VISITORIP AND LASTVISIT.DATEENTERED = STATS.DATEENTERED"
    SQL = SQL & " ORDER BY STATS.DATEENTERED DESC"
    Set objTrackIP = objConn.Execute(SQL)   
%>
<% Do While Not objTrackIP.EOF %>
            <tr class="row-a">
                <td><%=objTrackIP("DATEENTERED")%></td>
                <td class=""><%=objTrackIP("HTTPADDRESS")%></td>
            </tr>
<%
    objTrackIP.MoveNext
    Loop
%>
<%
    objDateEntered.MoveNext
    Loop
%>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

edit: I think problem is with my outer query. But I grouped them by DATEENTERED field, I dont know what else can I do.

Comment: Kids, when you see queries like this, don't copy them. These are BAD examples. You do not want to add SQL injection like that into your site. By the way, what URL is your page at, Efe?

Comment: @remus: I agree with you, but is the patronizing attitude really necessary?

Comment: why is it a bad query? how can I fix it?

Comment: @efe: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection then http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc676512.aspx . There's even an automated tool to detect sql injection vulnerabilities in classic asp: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/954476

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First query should be

```
"SELECT 
    DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEENTERED, 101) AS vDATE 
 FROM 
    STATS 
 WHERE 
    VISITORIP = '"& IPADDRESS &"'" 
 ORDER BY 
    DATEENTERED DESC"
```

then print the vData column

and the 2nd SQL

```
SELECT 
   VISITORIP, HTTPADDRESS, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEENTERED, 8) AS vTIME
FROM 
   STATS
WHERE
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEENTERED, 101) = '" & objDateEntered("vDATE") &"'
   AND VISITORIP = '"& IPADDRESS &"'
ORDER BY VISITORIP ASC, DATEENTERED DESC
```

I think this will do the trick..

Comment: gaby, thank you so much! I wonder why I complicated it so much. Again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in next code line:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEENTERED, 101) AS DATEENTERED
```

and then you group by this date

```
GROUP BY DATEENTERED
ORDER BY DATEENTERED DESC
```

You group and order by the varchar. 
As I think, you need to use another alias to date when you convert it ro varchar, but you really need to order by dateentered that is datetime type.

Comment: I tried it as: SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEENTERED, 101) AS ENTRY FROM STATS WHERE VISITORIP = '"& IPADDRESS &"' GROUP BY ENTRY ORDER BY DATEENTERED DESC. But I received the following error: Invalid column name 'ENTRY'.

Comment: maybe

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEENTERED, 101) AS ENTRY FROM STATS WHERE VISITORIP = '"& IPADDRESS &"' GROUP BY DATEENTERED ORDER BY DATEENTERED DESC
?

Comment: That work. But I still get outcome as 07/12/2009
 
07/12/2009
 
07/10/2009
 
07/10/2009
 
07/09/2009
 
07/09/2009
 
07/06/2009
 
07/06/2009
 
07/03/2009
 
07/03/2009
 
07/01/2009
 
06/29/2009
 
06/29/2009

Comment: Then I see I have wrong understand your question, because the dates are ordered in right descending order.

Answer (score 0):

It you're trying to get some visitor tracking happening have you thought of using something like [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics)?